# Netbeans 6.7 custom variable for ant task

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, classpath, netbeans6.7

I've got a problem which I couldn't solve for a few days, please help me.

I'd like to execute an ant-script within netbeans. the script needs a special classpath which a plugin/module made by myself puts into a "global-variable". The variable can be shown using the netbeans "Manage variables"-dialog. So it's working, I guess

Then I've tried to run the ant-script with: "run Target/advanced" and set the property to: enhanceClassPath=${MAG} (${MAG} contains the special classpah..)

Unfortunately the script contains in the property 'enhanceClassPath' still the value '${MAG}' instead the variable value..

I've got a working and simular example in eclipse, but hadn't any luck with netbeans, I guess the main problem is that netbeans doesn't support variables..

greez Chris

Answer (score 1):

you can use your [IDE variable](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IDEVariables) `MAG` in your ant script via [`${var.MAG}`](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IDEVariables#section-IDEVariables-UIChanges). don't assign it to a custom property (*enhanceClassPath*).

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?
I've set in NB a GlobalProperty called "var.MAG".
Then I tried to access it in the ant script with
<property name="cp" value="${var.MAG}">

but the value of cp is still not resolved..

Comment: Ok thanks.
But it didn't work.. not as custom property neither directly in ant..
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: it works for me - when i debug my (netbeans managed) ant script, i can see var.MAG in the debugger variables window.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/IDEVariables says:

  Variables are stored in build.properties in user directory and in properties file they are prefixed with "var."

build.properties is automatically loaded in a netbeans managed ant script via <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>. if your ant script is *not* managed by nb, you have to include "${netbeans.user}/build.properties" yourself - look into nbproject/build-impl.xml for how to.

Comment: Ah.. now I understand! Thanks a lot, I do really recognize your help!!

Comment: if you recognize my help, you could consider accepting my answer. thanks!